# Evaluation of Classifier Performance on Imbalanced Dataset with Lift Chart

Tags: unbalanced-classes, boosting

I trained a classifier on imbalanced dataset (label={0,1}) by assigning higher weight to rare event(label=1). Lift chart shows that the predicted and actual curves are very separated. I also trained one without weighting and the curves are very close.

I think this is because when punishing heavily on +1 will shift the probability score of the whole population towards +1. So how can I plot the lift chart so that the effect weighted classification is eliminated and the plot could show the performance as if no weights have been assigned?